# Вопрос по конструктору JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function Car(x,y) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
};

Car.prototype.draw = function () {
    let carHtml='<img src="car.png">';
    this.carElement=$(carHtml);
    this.carElement.css ({
        position:"absolute",
        left:this.x,
        top:this.y
    });
    $("body").append(this.carElement);
}
Car.prototype.moveRight = function () {
    this.x+=5;
    this.carElement.css({   
        left:this.x,
        top:this.y
    });
};
let tesla=new Car(1000,20);
let nissan=new Car(1000,400);
tesla.draw();
nissan.draw();
setInterval(nissan.moveRight,30);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы картинка через сетинтервал двигалась по экрану но отладчик ругается на вот этот кусок кода  `this.carElement.css({`   в методе moveRight, и ничего не происходит, хотя когда через консоль вручную вызываю метод этого объекта то картинка сдвигается на 5 пикселей влево как и должна, библиотека jquery подключена и отрисовываются объекты без проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setInterval(nissan.moveRight.bind(nissan), 30);
```

Comment: Объясните зачем добавлять bind и в него записывать ещё раз название объекта?Спасибо

Comment: Это написано по ссылке.